# Como comparar o valor de números guardados como VARCHAR no mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada `coordenadas_cache`, com 6 campos:

```
codigo (int, auto increment),
latitude_sul (VARCHAR(10)),
latitude_norte (VARCHAR(10)),
longitude_oeste (VARCHAR(11)),
longitude_leste (VARCHAR(11)),
endereco (VARCHAR(80))
```

Nela são guardados valores (bounds), que são limites de localizações/endereços do Google Maps, obtidas através de um JSON via HTTPS, ao se informar uma localização Latitude/Longitude.

Eu faço, em PHP uma query SQL que compara a latitude e longitude de um ponto, assim:

```
latitude_sul <= latitude_do_ponto<=latitude_norte
longitude_oeste <= longitude_do_ponto<=longitude_leste
```

Se essas condições forem válidas, significa que o ponto está dentro da cerca, e consequentemente naquele endereço.

No entanto, não estou conseguindo retornar o valor do campo `endereco` que contém a localização, porque não consigo comparar as duas strings de latitude e longitude com os VARCHARs, conforme a seguinte query:

```
SELECT coordenadas_cache.endereco FROM coordenadas_cache 
 WHERE latitude_sul <= latitude_do_ponto
   AND latitude_norte >= latitude_do_ponto
   AND longitude_leste <= longitude_do_ponto
   AND longitude_oeste >= longitude_do_ponto
```

Exemplo de valores enviados:

```
latitude_do_ponto = -29.123456
longitude_do_ponto = -53.123456
```

Existe alguma maneira de transformar os VARCHARs e as strings enviadas em INT durante a execução do SELECT, para que se possa fazer a comparação dos valores?

Comment: De curiosidade, não compensa já guardar em int mesmo? Se multiplicar por 10000000 vai ter coordenadas de -213 a +213 com 7 casas decimais (e se precisar de mais casas tem o bigint). Assim, vai ter muito mais velocidade nas comparações, e a base vai ocupar bem menos que a metade do espaço atual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar um cast para decimal. Assim:

```
SELECT coordenadas_cache.endereco 
  FROM coordenadas_cache 
 WHERE latitude_sul <= CAST('-29.123456' AS DECIMAL(10,5))
   AND latitude_norte >= CAST('-29.123456' AS DECIMAL(10,5))
   AND longitude_leste <= CAST('-53.123456' AS DECIMAL(10,5))
   AND longitude_oeste >= CAST('-53.123456' AS DECIMAL(10,5))
```

Ou então, usando as variáveis que você indicou:

```
SELECT coordenadas_cache.endereco 
  FROM coordenadas_cache 
 WHERE latitude_sul <= CAST(latitude_do_ponto AS DECIMAL(10,5))
   AND latitude_norte >= CAST(latitude_do_ponto AS DECIMAL(10,5))
   AND longitude_leste <= CAST(longitude_do_ponto AS DECIMAL(10,5))
   AND longitude_oeste >= CAST(longitude_do_ponto AS DECIMAL(10,5))
```

O cast irá converter os valores usando uma precisão de 5 casas decimais.